# Get to load "more" button for next page?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, scrapy

I am trying to click the "more" button for getting next set of pages.

Next page link Htmltags:

```html
<span id="direct_moreLessLinks_listingDiv" class="more_less_links_container" data-num-items="15" offset="45" data-type="listing">
<a id="button_moreJobs" rel="nofollow" href="#">More</a>
</span>
```

**Note:** when I am clicking the "more" button. It is loading the next page in the same page.

I am trying to click the next page using selenium:

Code part:

```html
self.driver.get('example.com')
        while True:
            more_btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "More"))
            )

            More.click()

            # stop when we reach the desired page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the link **by ID** and click it:

```
more_btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
               EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "button_moreJobs"))
           )
more_btn.click()
```

Since this is a `while True` loop, you need to figure out a way to stop the pagination and break the loop. This is something I can only make guesses about since you haven't provided an actual page you are working with.